# make Wordpress content span across 2 columns

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Wordpress and Bootstrap 3 framework and using ...

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

... to put the page content on the page. I want to put it in two columns (col-md-6) with the content spanning into two columns. but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Depends on how much control you have when you input the content in the admin panel, you can put html tags in if that's OK, i.e. wrap the content into 2 divs and set up the relevant classes. Otherwise, the current css column answer might do it, but it only works on certain browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the HTML with this structure, adding a simple class (maybe `column-2`), and using this CSS:

```
.column-2 {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/omxqx8u1/)

Learn more about CSS columns [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp).

Note: Supported in all modern browsers (with prefixes) and IE 10+. [See here](http://caniuse.com/#search=column).

Comment: my columns are set using bootstrap framework would this work with that?

Comment: You can check [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/split-wordpress-content-into-multiple-sections/), [this one](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/split-the-content-of-the_content), or [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-columns/). Hope this help ;) But yes, you can use CSS multicolumn solution with Bootstrap too.

Comment: The resources in the comments could be more helpful than the answer I guess haha +1